# get list of selected objects as string Blender python

Tags: python, arraylist, blender-2.67

I'm facing a rather easy to solve problem but I just don't know how to do it. I want blender to list all the objects selected as a string. Eg. if I run :

```
selection_names = bpy.context.selected_objects
print (selection_names)
```

it gives me this line:

```
[bpy.data.objects['Cube.003'], bpy.data.objects['Cube.002'], bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'], bpy.data.objects['Cube']]
```

But what I want is for `selection_names` is to print out as:

```
['Cube.001','Cube.002','Cube.003','Cube']
```

Answer (score 13):

The fastest way to solve this is through list comprehension :

`selection_names = [obj.name for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]`

which is the exact equivalent of:

```
selection_names = []
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    selection_names.append(obj.name)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
>> selection_names = bpy.context.selected_objects
>>> print (selection_names)
[bpy.data.objects['Armature 05.04 p'], bpy.data.objects['Armature 04.08 l'], bpy.data.objects['Armature 04.07 p'], bpy.data.objects['Armature 04.07 l'], bpy.data.objects['Armature 04.04 p'], bpy.data.objects['Armature 04.05 p'], bpy.data.objects['Armature 04.05 l']]

>>> for i in selection_names:
...     print(i.name)
...     
Armature 05.04 p
Armature 04.08 l
Armature 04.07 p
Armature 04.07 l
Armature 04.04 p
Armature 04.05 p
Armature 04.05 l
```

If you want them to become objects in an array, you can do this:

```
>>> SelNameArr=[]
>>> for i in selection_names:
...     SelNameArr.append(i.name)
...     
>>> SelNameArr
['Armature 05.04 p', 'Armature 04.08 l', 'Armature 04.07 p', 'Armature 04.07 l', 'Armature 04.04 p', 'Armature 04.05 p', 'Armature 04.05 l']
```